# Covert string of text into JSON

Tags: json

I keep receiving a JSON error "Make sure the ref is the correct JSON" Would anybody be able to advise how to get the below code into a readable JSON file?

```
"secret":"secret code","protoVersion":[0,17],"binVersion":10,"battery":69,"plugged":false,"platform":"android","features":{"URL":true,"FLAGS":"GAEoATgB"},"phone":{"wa_version":"2.18.248","mcc":"234","mnc":"010","os_version":"8.0.0","device_manufacturer":"phone make","device_model":"HWFIG-H","os_build_number":"FIG-LX1 8.0.0.132(C782)"},"pushname":"namehere","tos":0}]
```

Comment: u missing curly brackets at start/end end remove your final "]" use this tool 
https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Test it on https://jsonlint.com/ (in this case you miss     [{ in the beginning of your string)

Comment: You should try to make the JSON valid. As it stands, what you posted is not valid JSON. You need to add a `{` to the beginning of the string and remove the `]` from the end